# DynamoDB Streams with Lambda, how to process the records in order (by logical groups)?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I want to use DynamoDB Streams + AWS Lambda to process chat messages. Messages regarding the same conversation **user_idX:user_idY** (a room) must be processed in order. Global ordering is not important.

Assuming that I feed DynamoDB in the correct order (room:msg1, room:msg2, etc), how to guarantee that the Stream will feed AWS Lambda sequentially, with *guaranteed ordering of the processing of related messages (room) across a single stream*?

Example, considering I have 2 shards, how to make sure the logical group goes to the same shard?

I must accomplish this:

```
Shard 1: 12:12:msg3 12:12:msg2 12:12:msg1 ==> consumer
Shard 2: 13:24:msg2 51:91:msg3 13:24:msg1 51:92:msg2 51:92:msg1 ==> consumer
```

And not this (messages are respecting the order that I saved in the database, but they are being placed in different shards, thus incorrectly processing different sequences for the same room in parallel):

```
Shard 1: 13:24:msg2 51:92:msg2 12:12:msg2 51:92:msg2 12:12:msg1 ==> consumer
Shard 2: 51:91:msg3 12:12:msg3 13:24:msg1 51:92:msg1 ==> consumer
```

This official [post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-triggers-streams-lambda-cross-region-replication-app/) mentions this, but I couldn't find anywhere in the docs how to implement it:

> The relative ordering of a sequence of changes made to a single
>   primary key will be preserved within a shard. Further, a given key
>   will be present in at most one of a set of sibling shards that are
>   active at a given point in time. As a result, your code can simply
>   process the stream records within a shard in order to accurately track
>   changes to an item.

## Questions

1) How to set a partition key in DynamoDB Streams?

2) How to create Stream shards that guarantee partition key consistent delivery?

3) Is this really possible after all? Since the official article mentions: *a given key  will be present in at most one of a set of sibling shards that are active at a given point in time* so it seems that msg1 may go to shard 1 and then msg2 to shard 2, as my example above?

**EDITED:** In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993330/dynamo-streams-on-small-tables-consumed-by-multiple-instances) question, I found this:

> The amount of shards that your stream has, is based on the amount of
>   partitions the table has. So if you have a DDB table with 4
>   partitions, then your stream will have 4 shards. Each shard
>   corresponds to a specific partition, so given that all items with the
>   same partition key should be present in the same partition, it also
>   means that those items will be present in the same shard.

**Does this mean that I can achieve what I need automatically? *"All items with the same partition will be present in the same shard"*. Does Lambda respect this?**

**EDIT 2:** From the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/):

> The ordering of records across different shards is not guaranteed, and
>   processing of each shard happens in parallel.

I don't care about global ordering, just logical one as per example. Still, not clear if the shards group logically with this answer from the FAQ.

Comment: how-to-perform-ordered-data-replication-between-applications-by-using-amazon-dynamodb-streams - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-perform-ordered-data-replication-between-applications-by-using-amazon-dynamodb-streams/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-order processing for updates on the same key will happen automatically. As described in [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/realtime-data-processing-with-amazon-dynamodb-streams-and-aws-lambda-7302015/22), one Lambda function per active shard is run. Because all the updates for a particular partition/sort key appear in exactly one shard lineage, they are processed in order.