# How to choose between DynamoDB streams Kinesis adapter and Lambda triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

The AWS Docs show that DynamoDB streams can be consumed in 2 ways:

1. [DynamoDB Streams Kinesis adapter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.KCLAdapter.html)
2. [Lambda triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html)

The docs say that "the Amazon Kinesis Adapter is the recommended way to consume streams from Amazon DynamoDB", so in what scenarios would I want to use lambda triggers instead?

For example, I have heard the example use case of updating a leaderboard for a multiplayer game. In this case, the stream could be consumed by lambdas which update the leaderboard in a different database. Is Lambda the preferred tool in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Lambda is by far the best approach to consume a stream from this type of use-case. When you consume a stream using a Lambda trigger, you do not have to pay for the stream `GetRecords` calls.

If you use KCA then you have to manage a DynamoDB table used for leases and you also have to manage configurations and pay for `GetRecords`.

This post will provide a good overview:

[In dynamodb, what is the difference between using dynamo streams + lambda trigger versus kinesis streams + lambda trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74485429/in-dynamodb-what-is-the-difference-between-using-dynamo-streams-lambda-trigge)

Comment: Hi Lee, I believe the post which you linked is comparing _DynamoDB streams_ with _Kinesis Data Streams_. I think _Kinesis Data Streams_ is different to the _DynamoDB Streams Kinesis Adapter_. Am I mistaken? Also, I'm not sure what you meant by "KCA". Did you mean "KCL"?

Comment: Kinesis Data Streams is typically consumed with the kinesis client adapter. But even with DynamoDB streams you have the overhead managing leases, a lease table and also paying for the reads from the stream. Lambda is by far the winner here.